# "Lucky try" & "Recommended" shortcuts always appear on homescreen, how to remove it?

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, malware

I am getting shortcuts in my home screen. I try to delete it, but it is appearing once again. Shortcuts names: Lucky try, Recommended.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Confirmed malware, related: https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?/topic/165698-shortcuts-get-created/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a spammy app. Check the ones you've installed last before this trouble started:

1. From your home screen, go to the Android *Settings › Apps*
2. scroll the list to find above mentioned apps. For each app:

   1. open its entry
   2. scroll down to the end of the page opening, where you should find the permissions listed (which the app has requested)
   3. check if the app has the permission to create shortcuts

Alternatively, use a [Permission Checker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/security_permissions#group_379) – [aSpotCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.aSpotCat) is a good candidate for this, [CRAM App Analyser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.tgsoft.cram) seems to be capable of the same: showing you all existing permissions, and on selecting one of them, all the apps requesting it.

[image: aSpotCat] [image: CRAM App Analyser]
<sup>*aSpotCat* and *CRAM App Analyser* (source: the resp. Playstore page; click images for larger variants)</sup>

The related permission goes by the name [`INSTALL_SHORTCUT`](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/perms#INSTALL_SHORTCUT), and most likely will be titled "Install Shortcuts" or something similar.

Once you found the possible culprit, get rid of it: uninstall the app (if multiple, only one a time) and see whether the issue goes away. If the whole racket ended, you've got the troublemaker eliminated – and in case you've uninstalled other apps before on this road, it should be safe to re-install those as they were most likely not causing the issue.

Comment: i had done reset my  phone but after that it can't be okay. pls help me

Comment: Are you saying you did a factory-reset, and without having installed anything afterwards, that behavior continued?

Comment: yes sir, after factory reset i can't be okay,,,, i am very harrased from one week,,, pls help me sir

Comment: If you really didn't install any app after the factory-reset, and the problem is still present, that leaves only pre-installed software as a cause (unless some malware was able to exploit some bug to install itself to the system partition). Maybe you can update your question with a screenshot for additional details?

Comment: Looks much the same as [shortcuts being created automatically on the homecreen i touched an app called super flash light](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/102712/16575). Same app in use? // And you do not pre-install software yourself. The manufacturer does (hence the "pre": before you buy), and you cannot uninstall it then in most cases.

Comment: ya ya i think u r ryt after installing dis app  i think the problem is growned. but now i uninstalling dis app from my phone, bt phone is not okay

Comment: Check what other apps it might have drawn in (apps you didn't install yourself, or installed when chosing from what this app offered). Even if it "subscribed" you to some ad service, it needs some component to get them on your homescreen.

Comment: so what cn i do now????

Comment: If not even a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) solves the issue, that only leaves you to [re-install the OS](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rom-flashing/info).

Comment: so how to re install OS???

Comment: That's a different question. Follow the links I gave you in my previous comment and, if necessary, ask a new question on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a rooted phone. Using any root explorer, simply delete `kinguser.apk` app from `/system/app`.

Comment: *Comment by an anonymous user, incorrectly proposed as an edit:* If you can't delete `kinguser.apk` , open *Settings › Apps › All*, look for fake settings and kapk , then disable and force stop those apps.

Answer (score -1):

Look for "ExpandPointWall" and a fake "Settings" app and uninstall them.