# "Lucky try" & "Recommended" shortcuts being created automatically on the homecreen

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts, malware

I had installed xmod games apk. Then I had opened it. It showed me some 5 apps like advertisement. I had touched the app called "super flash light". After that, I am getting shortcuts in my home screen. I try to delete it but it is appearing one again. Shortcuts names: Lucky try, Recommended.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Most likely adware embedded in that app you've installed. Have you tried uninstalling the app? Does that stop it? Btw: this kind of adware violates the TOS of Google Play. So if uninstalling the app solves your issue, and you had installed it from Google Play – you should consider reporting it.

Comment: Confirmed malware, related: https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?/topic/165698-shortcuts-get-created/