# 2X Parallels Client App - Too Many Shortcuts!

Tags: home-screen-shortcuts

Without going into too much painstaking detail, I'm connecting to a 2X server setup remotely on my Android phone (LG Nexus 5X) using the official Parallels 2X client app from the Google Play store.

It works well enough, but every time I log in to my work servers... the app creates a shortcut on my home screen for every application link we have, of which there are a ton.  Pages worth.  If I don't remove them, the client just keeps piling copies of the shortcuts on top of shortcuts on top of shortcuts. It's a huge mess, and I have to manually delete each shortcut one by one every time I log in to clean up my home screen.

Is there any system-wide setting on the Android OS (v7.0) to not allow apps to create shortcuts (not just when they install, I know how to disable that, but in general)?  Or perhaps anyone with knowledge on the official Parallels 2X client app might know how to stop this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you only have the possibility to block an app from creating a shortcut on install.
I believe that it's against Googles Playstore rules to spam the user with such shortcuts. You can try to contact the developer and if they don't react you can contact Google.

[edit]
Additional information:
[How to Block Third Party Apps from Creative Spam Shortcuts on Home Screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/147625/how-to-block-third-party-apps-from-creative-spam-shortcuts-on-home-screen?rq=1)